# Boost shared_ptr does not destroy the object immediately

Tags: c++, boost, destructor, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am developing a Bayesian inference sampler in C++, which relays much on a tree, and this tree is implemented with the help of smart pointers (Boost's shared_ptr and weak_ptr).

During inference (i.e. running a long C++ function for 1-2 minutes), the tree is being changed much, creating and destroying many its nodes.

The inference process entirely (100% load) occupies the processor (one its thread, more precisely). For some reason new memory (for new nodes) is being occupied, but old memory is not being freed entirely, which yields in memory overflow after 1-2 minutes of inference.

Though, if I add pauses to the inference process, it seems the program entirely destroy old objects, and all work fine.

It seems for me that the reason is that destructor (or, more precisely, what happens after it, i.e. memory release) is being delayed for some reason.

Could you tell, please:
1) Does it seem to be a real problem?
2) If yes, how it is better to wait while "enough memory" would be released? What are standard strategies?

(The program is being run on Unix.)

Comment: To me it sounds like your shared_ptr's are still having references held to them and therefore not getting destroyed directly.  But honestly, hard to say without any code.

Comment: `shared_ptr` just calls `delete`. Are you sure that the observed behavior is not due to `delete` ? Because `delete` implementations are known which postpone actual deallaction, in the assumption that they can recycle the allocations.

Comment: MSalters, can you give a reference to information about delete implementation with postpone deallocations? I think it could be exactly my case. (Sorry, have not found myself.)

Comment: Have you tried adding a printf to the class destructor to log when it is invoked? That way you'll know if it's being destroyed or not.

Answer (score 2):

The memory problems you observe seem not to be situated in C++ itself. If a shared_ptr releases its memory, it does so immediately, not in some delayed manner. However, your operating system might delay the "real" release for some time as it sees fit. In programs like Windows' "Task Manager" that might look as if your program consumes more and more memory, while that is only the memory the OS reserves for you but you don't actually occupy. If your calculations produce such a heavy processor load, the scheduler might delay rather "unimportant" tasks (like freeing memory) until there is time, to not get in the way of more important things like your calculations.

However, freeing and allocating memory is expensive. And it seems that you free and allocate lots of memory interchangeably. You should consider to recycle that memory, either by doing your own memory management (like memory pools etc.), or by recycling the objects (i.e. the nodes) themselves, meaning not really destroying them but giving them back to some "node pool" and resetting them with new values. Both can be done in conjunction with shared_ptr.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell, please, if not to use memory pools conception, is there any way to either (1) control the scheduler priorities to perform deallocations as first priority, (2) or if it is not possible to adjust the scheduler, how reasonably and elegantly make pauses to wait for necessary deallocations?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have cycles in your tree, i.e. it uses `shared_ptr` for both child and parent pointers, which prevents automatic tree node destruction. You may be better off using plain pointers.

Comment: Or use strong pointers in one direction and weak pointers in the other direction. Or manually sever pointers when objects should be deleted.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It can not be simpler than plain pointers though.

Comment: It's usually simpler to not have to keep track of when it's safe to delete an object than to have to. With both of my approaches, you don't have to.

Comment: Sorry, but I use exactly weak_ptr for parents. It seems it is more problem with deallocation, not with shared_ptr's counters. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Every time I see a beginner using smart pointers for a tree they shoot both of their legs off.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, very funny, what you are proposing to use for trees with complex nodes? :) Perhaps, I have to change my implementation basing on your proposal.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Fair enough. I agree that smart pointers are easy to misuse. Dumb pointers are easier to understand.

Comment: If he adds pauses, the program destroys the old objects, so it does *not* look like circular refs. Using plain pointers because of the fear of circular refs does not sound good to me. Of course one should not use `shared_ptr` without figuring out how they behave in the situation, but using plain pointers is even more error prone, although things like double delete, access violations etc. are easier to debug. Instead of switching back to plain pointers i'd recommend getting familiar with `shared_ptr`'s peculiarities and using them correctly - if circular refs indeed are the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

when the last shared_ptr pointing to an object is destroyed, the object is deleted immediately. So what you get sounds quite strange. The only think I could imagine is that you have attached a garbage collector to your implementation... Otherwise double check that all old objects get destroyed.